# Why async.series doesn't respect the order of my tasks?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have a collection with many documents like these samples :

**Direct flight** <=> `Stops == 0` && `Thru_Point == ""`

```
{
    "Orig" : "PTH",
    "Dest" : "GMP",
    "Flight" : 126,
    "Stops" : 0,
    "Seats" : 169,
    "Ops_Week" : 3,
    "Eff_Date" : "2016-04-14",
    "Mkt_Al" : "XX",
    "Thru_Point" : "",
    "Arr_Time" : 1600,
    "Block_Mins" : 230

}
```

**Flight with stop** <=> `Stops == 1` && `Thru_Point != ""`

```
{
    "Orig" : "CIM",
    "Dest" : "LKR",
    "Flight" : 7756,
    "Stops" : 1,
    "Seats" : 70,
    "Ops_Week" : 2,
    "Eff_Date" : "2016-04-11",
    "Mkt_Al" : "YY",
    "Thru_Point" : "BHU",
    "Arr_Time" : 140,
    "Block_Mins" : 345 // the elapsed time 
}
```

Each document refers to one flight, and I'm trying to calculate a score for each document, but I have one difficult which is when I have a Stop Flight I should calculate the elasped time, for direct flight it's simple, the elapsed time equals the value in `Block_Mins`, but for flights with stop, I should calculate the elapsed time for each segment from `Orig` to `Thru_Point` and from `Thru_point` to `Dest`

```
mongoose.connection.on("open", function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;  
    var bulkUpdateOps = Vol.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(), 
        counter = 0;

    Vol.find({}).lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) throw err; 
        var locals = {};

        docs.forEach(function(doc) {            
            locals.c1 = 0.3728 + (0.00454 * doc.Seats);         
            locals.c3 = doc.Ops_Week;

            if (doc.Stops == 1) {               
                async.series([
                    // Load doc with first leg first
                    function(callback) {
                        Vol.findOne({ 
                            Mkt_Al: doc.Mkt_Al,
                            Orig: doc.Orig,
                            Dest: doc.Thru_Point                          
                        }).lean().exec(function (err, flight) {
                            if (err) return callback(err);
                            locals.first_leg = flight.Block_Mins;
                            callback();
                        });
                    },
                    // Load second leg doc 
                    // (won't be called before task 1's "task callback" 
                    // has been called)
                    function(callback) {                    
                        Vol.findOne({ 
                            Mkt_Al: doc.Mkt_Al,
                            Orig: doc.Thru_Point,
                            Dest: doc.Dest                          
                        }).lean().exec(function (err, flight) {
                            if (err) return callback(err);
                            locals.second_leg = flight.Block_Mins;
                            callback();
                        });
                    }
                ], function(err) { // This function gets called after the
                    // two tasks have called their "task callbacks"
                    if (err) throw err;
                    // Here locals will be populated with `first_leg` 
                    // and `second_leg`
                    // Just like in the previous example
                    var total_flight = locals.second_leg + locals.first_leg;                    
                    locals.c2 = 0.03;
                    locals.c4 = Math.pow((doc.Block_Mins / total_flight), -0.675);                    

                }); 
            } else {
                locals.c2 = 1;
                locals.c4 = 1;
            }

            counter++;
            console.log(locals);
            bulkUpdateOps.find({ "_id" : doc._id }).updateOne({ 
                "$set": { 
                    "Qsi": (locals.c1 * locals.c2 * locals.c3 * locals.c4) 
                } 
            });

            if (counter % 500 == 0) {
               bulkUpdateOps.execute(function(err, result) {          
                    if (err) throw err; 
                    bulkUpdateOps = Vol.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();                        
                });
            } 
        });

        if (counter % 500 != 0) {
            bulkUpdateOps.execute(function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err; 
                console.log(result.nModified);                
            });
        }   
    });
});
```

I tried this algorithm but I found myself with the same values, either flight with stop or direct flight !!! I think the problem came from the `async.series` or the `bulkupdate` should take its place also in `async.series` after other tasks...

Thank you in advance;

Comment: no one to help here ?

Answer (score 0):

Async.series is not guaranteed to be ran in the order it is declared.
Per [async.js documentation](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series):

> Note that while many implementations preserve the order of object properties, the ECMAScript Language Specification explicitly states that
>
> > The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties is not specified.
>
> So if you rely on the order in which your series of functions are executed, and want this to work on all platforms, consider using an array.

You could use `async.waterfall()` instead, which makes perfect sense in the case you're using. With minor adjustments in your code you can make this change. Here's an example:

```
(...)
docs.forEach(function(doc) {            
    locals.c1 = 0.3728 + (0.00454 * doc.Seats);         
    locals.c3 = doc.Ops_Week;

    if (doc.Stops == 1) { 
        async.waterfall([
            // Load doc with first leg first
            function(callback) {
                Vol.findOne({ 
                    Mkt_Al: doc.Mkt_Al,
                    Orig: doc.Orig,
                    Dest: doc.Thru_Point                          
                }).lean().exec(function (err, flight) {
                    if (err) return callback(err);
                    // locals.first_leg = flight.Block_Mins; //no need to save it in locals variable.
                    callback(null, flight.Block_Mins); //passing "first_leg" forward to next function 
                });
            },
            // Load second leg doc 
            // (won't be called before task 1's "task callback" 
            // has been called)
            function(first_leg, callback) {                    
                Vol.findOne({ 
                    Mkt_Al: doc.Mkt_Al,
                    Orig: doc.Thru_Point,
                    Dest: doc.Dest                          
                }).lean().exec(function (err, flight) {
                    if (err) return callback(err);
                    // locals.second_leg = flight.Block_Mins; //same as first leg. No need to save it in a local variable
                    callback(null, first_leg+flight.Block_Mins); //passing "total_flight" forward to next function 
                });
            }
            ], function(err, total_flight) { // This function gets called after the
                if (err) throw err;
                locals.c2 = 0.03;
                locals.c4 = Math.pow((doc.Block_Mins / total_flight), -0.675);                    

        });
    } else {
        (...)
```